# Static graphics in Gtk DrawingArea

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to draw some static and some dynamic graphics on Gtk drawing area. In Gtk drawing area, on every call of queue_draw, it clears all the graphics already drawn, and for complex graphics this is very time consuming.

Is there a way that I specifically delete some graphics, and add a few new graphics while the already drawn graphics remains undeleted?

for example in [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOzVt.png), I want to keep black line unchanged unless drawing area window size changes, I want to keep 3 out of 5 red spots and add some new blue spots so that new image looks like [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnnja.png).

If this question is already answered please share link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know 2 ways to solve your problem.

1. Store [paths](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/1.10/cairo-Paths.html).
   You can draw something (with `line_to`, `arc`, etc) on an empty `cairo_t`, then call `cairo_copy_path` and store that path somewhere. On next `"draw"` you should call `cairo_append_path` to apply that path.
2. You can store entire cairo surfaces. For example, create cairo_image_surface, fill it and then use it like this:

   ```
   draw_surface (cairo_surface_t *src,
                 cairo_t         *dst,
                 gdouble          x,
                 gdouble          y)
   {
     cairo_surface_mark_dirty (src);
     cairo_save (dst);
     cairo_translate (dst, x, y);
     cairo_set_source_surface (dst, src, 0, 0);
     cairo_paint (dst);
     cairo_restore (dst);
   }
   ```